# How to convert pixel distance to steps

Tags: javascript

[image]

I want to calculate the step number based on the container width and the distance of the line in relation to the container.

I was able to calculate the steps, but only with the minimum step being 0. However, in my scenario, the minimum step can be greater than 0 and so far I haven't been able to figure out how to bake that in the calculation.

**Check the full example from this [codepen](https://codepen.io/joonaspaakko/pen/BaageJg?editors=0011).**

```js
// Small example:
// In this code, line distance 0 corresponds to step 0, but I want it to 
// correspond to step 100, since that is supposed to be the minimum step. 

var lineDistance = 0; // px
var maxDistance = 704; // px
var minSteps = 100; //step
var maxSteps = 500; //step
var step = Math.floor( (lineDistance/maxDistance) * maxSteps );
```

**Some examples of static values that the step calculation should return:**

*The end goal is to be able to calculate the step with dynamic values...*

- If **line distance** is `0`, the `step` returns `100`
- If **line distance** is `10`, the `step` returns `105`
- If **line distance** is `352`, the `step` returns `300`

  - *352 is half of the maximum distance*
  - *300 the halfway point between min and max steps*
- If **line distance** is `704`, the `step` returns `500`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand right you just need to interpolate distance to steps, then you need to find length of both intervals first:

```js
const distanceLength = maxLength - minLength; // probably maxLength - 0 in your case
const stepLength = maxSteps - minSteps;
```

Then normalise your value (find distance diff):

```js
const distanceDiff = lineDistance - minDistance; // probably just lineDistance in your case
```

Then convert it into absolute units:

```js
const distanceRate = distanceDiff / distanceLength;
```

Then convert into steps:

```js
const stepsDiff = distanceRate * stepsLength;
```

And shift with steps min value:

```js
const steps = minSteps + stepsDiff;
```

Comment: That's it! So I went from this `Math.floor( (lineDistance/maxDistance) * maxSteps );` **to this →** `Math.floor( minSteps + (lineDistance / maxDistance) * (maxSteps - minSteps) );`. I "minified" your code to fit [my example code](https://codepen.io/joonaspaakko/pen/xxxooxz?editors=0011) a bit better and I removed minDistance from the calculation, since it is always 0 in my case.

Comment: No no. That was **incredibly helpful**. I just wanted to make sure there's a working example with the original code for anyone who stumbles across this question.